# Comparing two circularly shifted matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, equivalence-relations

I am looking for a way to compare two matrices A and B where B is the result of circularly shifting rows of A i.e.

A = [1 2 3;4 5 6], B = [4 5 6;1 2 3]

Is there an operator or metric that would treat these matrices as equivalent?

The reason I'd like to do this is I have an optimization problem where I am minimizing a cost function involving B but need solutions that are consistent with the original data A (i.e. B is the result of circularly shifting rows of A).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could take the metric
$$
d(A,B) = \min_\sigma \|A - \sigma(B)\|
$$
That is: for any norm $\|\cdot\|$, take the minimum of the norm of the difference between $A$ and the possible permutations of $B$.  So, for your $2 \times 3$ example, we'd have
$$
d(A,B) = \min\left\{\left\|A - \pmatrix{B_1\\B_2} \right\|,\left\|A - \pmatrix{B_2\\B_1} \right\|\right\}
$$
where $B_i$ are the rows of $B$.

Comment: Did this answer your question?  Is something I said unclear?  Is there something in my answer that you're unsure of?  If so, let me know.  If, on the other hand, you've found this answer satisfactory, accept it by clicking the check mark next to my question.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay in response but it took some time to implement your suggestion in my algorithmn. It was very helpful thanks!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Do such metrics have name?

Comment: @Surb I know that Hausdorff distance is relayed. I don't know if it's exactly this, though